# Budgie dynamic workspaces?

Tags: workspaces, budgie

I recently installed Ubuntu Budgie after using regular Ubuntu for a while. I immediately loved Budgie, but the only feature I miss from Gnome is the dynamic workspaces. Is there any way to get these on Budgie?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly [ideas for dynamic workspaces](https://github.com/solus-project/budgie-desktop/issues/1316) in Budgie, but it did not yet come into reality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some shortcuts to use workspaces on "Keyboard Settings", "Customize Shortcuts" and go to "Navigation". The default to change workspaces on budgie is SUPER + PAGE UP and SUPER + SHIFT + DOWN. If you want more than 2 workspaces you can launch "Budgie Desktop Settings", go to "Desktop" and change number of virtual desktop